# Geostationary satellite projection to be introduced in GDAL

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, proj, well-known-text

I'm working on raster files and their spatial reference system is:

```
PROJCS["Geostationary_Satellite",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Unknown datum based upon the custom ellipsoid",
        DATUM["D_Not specified (based on custom ellipsoid)",
            SPHEROID["Custom_ellipsoid",6378140,298.252981]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Geostationary_Satellite"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["satellite_height",35785831],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

How can I introduce it to GDAL? Is there proj4 or WKT equivalent to it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run gdalsrsinfo on the WKT you posted, and it returns for PROJ.4:

```
+proj=geos +lon_0=0 +h=35785831 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378140 +b=6356754.99999591 +units=m +no_defs
```

But i have no comparison values to check that on cs2cs.

Comment: nice! I didn't know about gdalsrsinfo. I'm afraid I didn't understand you last comment on "cs2cs" and I don't know what it is.

Comment: with cs2cs you can translate single coordinates from one CRS into another. It is part of GDAL.